# Createmeta using jirapython

Tags: jira, python-jira

Trying to know all the mandatory fields for an issue type Testcase in JIRA using the below statement

defined params as list with items projectIds, IssueType = Testcase, IssueType Id =

"jira._get_json('issue/createmeta', params)".

But i am not able to retrieve the fields
output is alist with
projects
issuetypes, 
subtask, 
description,
avatarUrls,
key,
Self,
expand

Let me know is there any issue with statement I used or please post a way to retrieve all  the mandatory fields for specific issue type using jira python

Answer (score 0):

The way I have been doing this for specific fields:

```
    issue = jira.issue(TestCase)
    issue_type_name = issue.fields.issuetype.name
    issue_type_id = issue.fields.issuetype.id
```

---

Another way to do this getting all the meta is:

```
    issue = jira.issue(TestCase)
    print(issue.raw)
```

or

```
    jira.createmeta(projectKeys='TestCaseProject', projectIds=['TestCase'],expand=None)
```

Source: http://pythonhosted.org/jira/